# How to debug a resolvejs application using VSCode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, resolvejs

I'm using Visual Studio Code.
I just created a resolvejs application.

How to run the application step by step from vscode ?

Here is my debugging setup (in .vscode\launch.json):

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Debug",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/run.js",
  "args": [
    "dev"
  ],
  "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node",
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "--nolazy",
    "--inspect"
  ]
}
```

My breakpoints in my command handlers do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although file `run.js` is some kind of entry point in `resolve` framework-based application, it is not actual entry point for runtime phase. When `resolve` application is being launched by `yarn dev` / `npm run dev` command, in fact two actions are performed: building bundle using `run.js` (which by default uses `config.[MODE].js` files for appropriate mode) and launching target bundle in separate process with watch mode, which causes automatic rebuild on every file change in project (aka hot reload).

Bundle is stored at `<APP_DIR>/dist/common/local-entry/local-entry.js`. To allow debugging from IDE, spawned debug `nodejs` should invoke target bundle directly. It can be reached by separating application compile- and runtime phases.

`Resolve` includes command for application building without run it - `yarn build` / `npm run build`. This command builds application in production mode, but this behavior can be easily modified to development mode by editing `run.js` entry point - just find line `case 'build':` and replace following line from `await build(merge(baseConfig, prodConfig))` to `await build(merge(baseConfig, devConfig))`. Or additional script for building app in dev mode can be appended, like `yarn build-dev` - amount of possible scripts is unlimited.

Then just run command `yarn build` and start debugger with pointing entry point as `${workspaceFolder}/dist/common/local-entry/local-entry.js`. If source maps had built right, breakpoints should work fine.